# how to convert short to byte array in Objective-c?

Tags: c#, objective-c, bitconverter

In C# short can be converted to byteArray like this

```
   public void WriteShort(short value)
    {
        WriteBytes(flip(BitConverter.GetBytes(value)));
    }
```

I want to implement this in C or Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C (considering short is 2 bytes), you could use this:

```
char* short_to_byteArr (short value)
{
   static char byte_arr[] = {};
   byte_arr[0] = value & 0x00FF;
   byte_arr[1] = (value>>8) & 0x00FF;
   return byte_arr;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, a + will be appriciated :P If it solves your problem, you could also mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for the union datatype.  Assuming a short is always the same size...

```
union
{
   short s;
   unsigned char bytes[2];
}u;
```